# I have a error in my code about "System.Format.Exception"

Tags: c#, forms, winforms

I'm creating a small program, but it throws an error.

> System.Format.Exception

It was good after I added the last line about:
- If the user does not enter any price it will show a MessageBox error.

```
private void button2_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    float mont,ope,mont_ht;
    mont = float.Parse(text_entrer.Text); // ERROR HERE : 'System.Format.Exception'
    if (radioButton4.Checked)
    { 
        text_resultat.Text = mont.ToString(); 
    }
    else if(radioButton5.Checked && radioButton1.Checked)
    {
        ope = mont * 20 / 100;
        mont_ht = mont + ope;
        text_resultat.Text = mont_ht.ToString();
    }
    else if (radioButton5.Checked && radioButton2.Checked)
    {
        ope = mont * 12 / 100;
        mont_ht = mont + ope;
        text_resultat.Text = mont_ht.ToString();
    }
    else if (radioButton5.Checked && radioButton3.Checked)
    {
        ope = mont * 5 / 100;
        mont_ht = mont + ope;
        text_resultat.Text = mont_ht.ToString();
    }

    if (String.IsNullOrEmpty(text_entrer.Text))
    {
        MessageBox.Show("no montant","EROR", MessageBoxButtons.OK, MessageBoxIcon.Warning);     
    }
}
```

Here a screenshot with the error and debug value:

[image: enter link description here]

Comment: I can't even read that properly and I can tell it means you are converting something to a float that isnt a float. Check the input before you try to do stuff with it

Comment: What is the value of `text_entrer.Text` ?

Comment: it's the first text zone where the user will add the price

Comment: Damned I've ask a question when the answer was in the post. The code block is too long, I'am editing you question to make it containt only the usefull information. So other don't get lost.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The immediate reason of the exception is that `text_entrer.Text` contains the string which can't be parsed into `float` (e.g. `bla-bla-bla` - is not a valid floating point value). I suggest using `TryParse` instead of `Parse`:

```
   using System.Globalization;

   ...
   float mont,ope,mont_ht;

   if (!float.TryParse(text_entrer.Text, 
                       NumberStyles.Any, 
                       CultureInfo.InvariantCulture, // or CultureInfo.CurrentCulture 
                       out mont) {
     if (text_entrer.CanFocus)
       text_entrer.Focus();

     MessageBox.Show($"{text_entrer.Text} is not a valid floating point value", 
                       Application.ProductName, 
                       MessageBoxButtons.OK, 
                       MessageBoxIcon.Warning);

     return;
   }
   ...
   if (radioButton4.Checked) 
     ...
```

Answer (score 0):

Apparently, an empty string in `text_entrer.Text` (i.e. "user don't enter any price") is not a valid numeric value and this should be checked *before* any conversion is attempted (i.e. before `float.Parse`). So move your value check to the beginning of the method and exit the method if the check fails:

```
private void button2_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    if (String.IsNullOrEmpty(text_entrer.Text))
    {
        MessageBox.Show("no montant","EROR", MessageBoxButtons.OK, MessageBoxIcon.Warning);
        return;
    }
    float mont,ope,mont_ht;
    mont = float.Parse(text_entrer.Text); //I HAVE THE PROBLEM HERE
    //..............
}
```

Moreover, you'd better secure from any invalid non-numeric input using `float.TryParse`:

```
if (!float.TryParse(text_entrer.Text, out mont))
{
    MessageBox.Show("Montant invalide","EROR", MessageBoxButtons.OK, MessageBoxIcon.Warning);
    return;
}
```